# Fragment cant remove Databinding.getRoot() with the Transaction had setCustomAnimations()？

Tags: android, android-fragments, data-binding

I have a question about the `fragment` , I cant remove the rootView from Databinding , I had deal with this problem for a long time.but not find the solution.

the Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

first show my code :

```
public class TestRootViewFragment extends BaseFragment {
FragmentTestRootBinding binding;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (binding == null) {
        binding = FragmentTestRootBinding .inflate(inflater, container, false);
        binding.texttitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                routeTo(new TestViewFragment(),null);
            }
        });
    }
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) binding.getRoot().getParent();
    if (parent != null) {
        parent.removeView(binding.getRoot());
        parent.removeAllViews();
    }
    return binding.getRoot();
}


protected void routeTo(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (getActivity() instanceof BaseActivity) {
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()

     //.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_right_in,R.anim.slide_left_out)
                .replace(((BaseActivity) getActivity()).getFragId(), fragment)
                .addToBackStack(tag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

}

this is my fragment code ,have a Databinding as a Member variables，and when this fragment is pop back , I dont need to inflate the databinding , use the pre one . this is my purpose. but it not work. you can  see  i had dismiss the `setCustomAnimations()` , it can work now ,but I need the Aniamtions.

I find out not wirte the `setCustomAnimations()`,the `binding.getRoot().getParent()` is null always. dont need to removeViews().

But I need the Animations . And with the `setCustomAnimations()`, the `binding.getRoot().getParent()` not null. then I want to remove the parent.

I use the `parent.removeAllViews()` & `parent.removeView(binding.getRoot());`
.then I found the parent.childcount is ZERO!!!,and then the `bind.getRoot().getParent()` is still there ,not removed.

what should I solve this problem (Dont mind the BaseFragment and the BaseActivity)